# Не работает TaskExecutor в Spring

Tags: java, spring, многопоточность

Есть конфиг

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public TaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(4);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(4);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("thread");
        executor.initialize();
        executor.setAwaitTerminationSeconds(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        executor.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
        return executor;
    }

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }
}
```

есть класс

```
@Service
public class ThreadExecutorService {

    @Autowired
    TaskExecutor taskExecutor;

    public  void generateCameraReport() throws JsonProcessingException {
    
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            taskExecutor.execute(() -> {
                System.out.println(1);
            });
        }
   
    }
}
```

В дебагере исполнение не проваливается внутрь `taskExecutor.execute(() -> {` точка останова на печати вообще не срабатывает, все время скачет между пока цикл не пройдет `for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) { taskExecutor.execute(() ->`

Подскажите как запустить исполнение, бин TaskExecutor срабатывает мой, в дебагере видны его настройки. Java 17 Spring Boot Starter 3.0.2

Comment: *"все время скачет между пока цикл не пройдет"* - кто именно скачет и между чем?

Answer (score -1):

используйте аннотацию @[Async](https://www.tune-it.ru/web/romo/blog/-/blogs/12523232) от спринга

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: в ссылке, что я предоставил, довольно подробная информация

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)